# External connection issue on Openshift 4 with confluent helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, openshift, kubernetes-helm, confluent-platform

I'm trying to use this confluent helm chart:
https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts
I know it is not maintained anymore, but I cannot use the another one, because of firewall issue.

I installed it on our dev Openshift 4 cluster, but I'm having problem when I test my application from local. I cannot access to the cluster from local.

The error message:

```
2022-12-05 10:46:40.532  WARN 15096 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-1, groupId=consumer] Error connecting to node prf-confluent-cp-kafka-0.prf-confluent-cp-kafka-headless.lapc-dev:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)

java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (prf-confluent-cp-kafka-0.prf-confluent-cp-kafka-headless.lapc-dev)
```

I enabled the the external listeners:

```
  "advertised.listeners": |-
   EXTERNAL://${HOST_IP}:$((32090 + ${KAFKA_BROKER_ID}))
  "listener.security.protocol.map": |-
   PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
```

and the nodeport:

```
nodeport:
  enabled: true
  servicePort: 9092
  firstListenerPort: 32090
```

I see the following in the logs (I masked the ip with "x"):

```
$ kubectl logs prf-confluent-cp-kafka-0 --container cp-kafka-broker  | grep liste
        advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://prf-confluent-cp-kafka-0.prf-confluent-cp-kafka-headless.lapc-dev:9092,EXTERNAL://10.xxx.x.xx:32090
        control.plane.listener.name = null
        controller.listener.names = null
        early.start.listeners = null
        inter.broker.listener.name = null
        listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
        listeners = PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:32090
        remote.log.metadata.manager.listener.name = null
```

How can I troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I used a wrong port. Now I'm using this and it is working.

```
nodeport:
  enabled: true
  servicePort: 19092
  firstListenerPort: 32090
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you open your firewall to download and use Strimzi, which RedHat maintains to be compatible with OpenShift.

Kubernetes service names will never be accessible from your local machine. You'll need to either `kubectl port-forward`, or find if there's a NodePort exposed for the bootstrap address. Look with `kubectl get svc` (or whatever the equivalent `oc` command is), and connect to the **IP:port** of the exposed node.